# Null pointer exception on webEngine.load() when running jar

Tags: java, javafx, maven-shade-plugin, javafx-webengine, uberjar

I'm using the maven shade plugin to create an uberjar from my javaFX application with all its JavaFX dependencies. The application uses javafx.controls & javafx.web, and was made with JavaFX 12.0.1.

I am able to run the jar that maven creates, and it runs fine for 70 or so lines until it encounters in the code `webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("web/main/main.html").toExternalForm());` at that point, it throws a null pointer exception.

I know that it's a problem exclusively with the jar because the application runs fine when I simply run the class files with the javaFX modules.

I've tried messing around with pom.xml extensively, but to no avail. I included every dependency I could think of, messed with the versions, and tried multiple random plugins I saw others using, but to no avail. It didn't help that there were very few examples online using javafx.web (I think that the problem *might* be originating there, as WebEngine is javafx.web), and the documentation for shade is extremely confusing.

Here's my pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>something</groupId>
    <artifactId>something</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <javafx.version>12.0.1</javafx.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- javafx dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
          <version>12.0.1</version>
          <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
          <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
          <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.fuckyou.Launcher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.something.Launcher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried with an absolute path to the html file? like `getClass().getResource("/com/something/web/main/main.html")`

Comment: Still throws a null pointer.

Comment: Can you verify that the html file is included in the jar?

Comment: `new File("web/main/main.html").exists();` returns false when run in Main... So I guess the html file isn't in the jar? How do I fix this?

Comment: Try to unzip the jar and see if the file is there. File() can be misleading if you don't set the correct path.

Comment: Unzipping the jar the html file's there, and in the correct path.

Comment: It works for me. Are you running your jar with Java 12?

Comment: Yup, java 12.0.1

Comment: I just did a quick test, and it works fine for me. Can you post your related code including the exact html location?

Comment: Here's the sourcecode on github https://github.com/KeinR/Java_Chat_Client/tree/master/src
by the way this version is only in the default package; com.something was created when I was trying different things with maven

Comment: You must follow the convention for sources and resources: use `src/main/java/`and `src/main/resources`, you must use a package for sources. Move them to something like `src/main/java/com/mypackage`. And you have to use an absolute path (like `"/web/main/main.html") to the resources, if `getClass()` refers to a class in a different package name than the resource.

Comment: Oh, it works! Thank you so much!